# How do you get another Eclipse workspace to 'see' project added to an existing Git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git

I had a GitHub repository with about 4 Eclipse projects shared between my laptop and desktop.

Then I added a 5th project, while working on my desktop computer.

How do I get my laptop to see the new project? (other than the obvious but inconvenient, deleting and re-cloning) (and no, a simple Fetch/Pull doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an import of the project, so open the import wizard (File > Import > Git > Projects from Git).
See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Wizard_for_project_import

[Edit - adds more details:]

First pull - fetch will only update the local repository, not the working tree.
Then:

[image: Step1: State before import]

[image: Step2: Import > Projects from]

Press "Next" twice...

[image: Step3: New project appears in git import wizard]

[image: Step4: Carry on working with the new project]

Comment: The "Import Projects From Git" dialog does not list the projects that were recently added (commited and pushed) to the repository in the other machine. Even after doing a Fetch, it's still not there.